# Why can't Ruby find OpenSSL at compile time?

Tags: ruby, openssl, makefile, homebrew

I'm on OSX and recently updated OpenSSL using Homebrew. I also ran `brew link openssl --force` in a (possibly misguided) attempt to ensure I always use the updated version.

Now I'm trying to install Ruby 2.1.1 using [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) 0.4.2.

During that process, ruby-install sets some options for Ruby about where to find various libraries. You can [see in the code](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/blob/v0.4.2/share/ruby-install/ruby/functions.sh#L24) that the first path it adds to `opt-dir` is the output of `brew --prefix openssl`. If I run that myself, I get `/usr/local/opt/openssl`.

Yet if I run `ruby-install ruby 2.1.1`, it eventually produces output that includes:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib'
```

That directory does exist; I can `ls` it. Why isn't it found?

Comment: That quote between the `-L` and the first `/` looks off to me.

Comment: @EtanReisner - oh, good catch. Didn't notice that.

Comment: Yeah, good catch. I hate spending hours on a stupid typo :)

Comment: Nathan - be careful at runtime. OS X does *not* honor Linux/GCC `LD_PRELOAD` or `rpaths`. So there's a good possibility you will link against 0.9.8 at runtime (even though you compiled against 1.0.1 at compile time). Your symptoms will be unexplained crashes in unexpected places for trivial programs. It can be quite tricky to get `@rpath` correct on Mac OS X. See [DYLD(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html).